# Retrieve duplicates based on a column

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following sheet where I need to retrieve only duplicates based on the column K in this example. Please bear in mind that I actually have over 10k data and I need to retrieve them from a different spreadsheet, but I could use some help with the formula.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Your post mentions "duplicates based on the column Q"; but there is nothing shown in Column Q in your posted image. Did you mean Column K?

Comment: Yes, I did. Question was edited. Thank you for noticing it.

Comment: Be sure to see my updated post, including a version for some international locales.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formula should work for you:

`=ArrayFormula({J1:L1; FILTER(J2:L,J2:J<>"",COUNTIF(K2:K,K2:K)>1)})`

The curly brackets `{ }` allow us to build a virtual array.

`J1:L1` will place your original headers at the top.

The semicolon means "move down to the next row" (i.e., place the results underneath the headers).

`FILTER` will filter ***in*** only entries where Col J is not blank and where there the `COUNTIF` from Col K is more than 1 (i.e., where there are duplicates).

If the formula does not work, you are likely in an international locale that uses semicolons as parameter delineations. In that case, use this version of the formula:

`=ArrayFormula({J1:L1; FILTER(J2:L;J2:J<>"";COUNTIF(K2:K;K2:K)>1)})`

Comment: This works perfectly and your explanation is great. Thank you! I adapt it to my formula and it works!!

Comment: Glad to hear it. And thanks for marking the post as "Best Answer." This helps the entire community, because it allows volunteer contributors to see at a glance which issues have already been fully resolved, and it allows future site visitors to easily find the answer as it relates to their own similar questions or issues.